# How to make this Java method generic

Tags: java, oop, generics, methods, generic-collections

I have a java method that i'm trying to make generic so that it can take a list of 2 different types of object as a parameter. (Trivial example shown below). These 2 different objects will both always have the methods getDate() and getHour(). The code looks like this:

```
public <T> List<T> getListOfStuff(List<T> statistics) {

    List<T> resultList = new ArrayList<T>(statistics.size());

    if(statistics.size() > 0){
        resultList.add(statistics.get(0));

        int date = Integer.parseInt(resultList.get(0).getDate());
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(resultList.get(0).getHour());
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

However this doesn't work. These two lines don't work:

```
int date = Integer.parseInt(resultList.get(0).getDate());
int hour = Integer.parseInt(resultList.get(0).getHour());
```

The errors say:
"The method getDate() is undefined for the type T" and 
"The method getHour() is undefined for the type T"

It offers me a suggestion to add a cast to the method receiver but it won't let me use T and instead forces the object name upon me like this which won't work for me:

```
int date = Integer.parseInt((ObjectName1)resultList.get(0).getDate());
int hour = Integer.parseInt((ObjectName1)resultList.get(0).getHour());
```

Is there any way to do what I want here?

Comment: Is this because you can't just create an interface?

Comment: Do these 2 different types have a common ancestor? i.e. a base class or an interface

Comment: More precisely, are these methods *inherited* from a common ancestor?

Comment: And what is `ObjectName1`? Is it the common ancestor of the two types you mentioned or is it one of the types that has `getDate` and `getHour` methods?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes they do, but unfortunately the getDate() and getHour() methods are not defined in that class and I cant change that class.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, see comment above

Comment: @Stackman but can you modify `ObjectName1` and its sibling class?

Comment: @Stackman I mean, why can't you create a common interface and make both `ObjectName1` and (lets suppose) `ObjectName2` implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use the following:

```
public <T extends ObjectName1> List<T> getListOfStuff(List<T> statistics) {
    List<T> resultList = new ArrayList<>(statistics.size());

    if (!statistics.isEmpty()) {
        resultList.add(statistics.get(0));

        int date = Integer.parseInt(resultList.get(0).getDate());
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(resultList.get(0).getHour());
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

The only `List`s that can be passed to this method now must either hold `ObjectName1` or an object that extends it.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. Unfortunately this wont work for my situation because the 2 classes both have getDate() and getHour() methods but those methods are defined in those 2 classes and not in one of the common super classes that the 2 classes inherit from. So this is probably a sign of bad class design I guess. Those common properties/methods should really be in a common super class. If this was the case then I would be able to use this way of making the method generic.

Answer (score 2):

Your method specifies to use a type `T` about which all the compiler knows is that it extends `Object`. `Object` does not have the methods you invoked. You have to assert that the type has the methods you use. For that you need `<T extends Foo>`, where `Foo` is a type with those methods.

`ObjectName1` is one of the worst names for a type possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That makes sense.

Regarding the name 'ObjectName1' - I changed the type name when I posted the question here as I didnt want to include the real code. Its just for an example.